# ts-loader -> file-loader doesn't resolve require dependencies

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-file-loader, ts-loader

I want to create a service worker.

**DISCLAMER**:
I don't wanna use [serviceworker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin), it adds a lot of overhead that I simply don't need. I'm 100% sure that webpack is able to serve transpiled js/ts files as static files.

So I have `main.ts` and `sw.ts`:

- `main.ts` should be transpiled via `ts-loader` and injected into `index.html`, when I run `webpack-dev-server` `main.ts` should support autoreload , as dev-server does by default.
- `sw.ts` on the other hand should be transpiled via `ts-loader` as well and it **SHOUDN'T** be injected into `index.html`. Also if I run `webpack-dev-server`, the dev-server shouldn't add hotreload js code there. I just want `sw.js` to be transplied.
- Also I would like to have a reference to `sw.js` during runtime from `main.js`. File-loader should provide it the same way as it does it for `.css files`.

### Attemp #1

My first attemp was to create 2 entries in webpack config like below:

```
entry: {'main': './src/main.ts', 'sw':'./src/sw.ts'},
```

To prevent `sw.ts` from injecting I could use `index.ejs` and manually check  js filename for [if](http://ejs.co/). This scenario works but while being on dev-server, webpack-dev-server adds hotreload code and `sw.js` fails at runtime within `window not defined`, which is logical, since service workers don't have window object.

### [Attemp #2, link to github](https://github.com/Deathangel908/sw-ts)

But then I tried `file-loader`, which looks like below:

**webpack.config.js**:

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/main.ts'],
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({hash: true, template: 'src/index.html'}),
  ],
  devtool: '#source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /sw\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: '',
          name: 'sw.js?[sha512:hash:base64:6]',
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**main.ts**;

```
import './sw.ts'
console.log('main.ts');
```

**sw.ts**:

```
import {LoggerFactory, LogStrict} from 'lines-logger';
console.log('sw file');
let loggerFactory: LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(LogStrict.LOG_WITH_WARNINGS);
```

Output **sw.js**:

```
import { LoggerFactory, LogStrict } from 'lines-logger';
console.log('sw file');
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(LogStrict.LOG_WITH_WARNINGS);
```

Why webpack doesn't resolve module dependencies? Is there another approach to handle service worker?

Answer (score -1):

My advice (you're not going to like it) is that service workers have some complexity involved. I recommend using a project like WorkBox to make your life easier:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/generate-service-worker/webpack

I've blogged about this in the past in case it helps: https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2017/11/the-typescript-webpack-pwa.html

Apologies, I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for. (Related issue on ts-loader: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/804 )